# Can localstorage data be placed in the HTTP header?

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers, local-storage, session-storage

I want to use localStorage on the client side and right now I am sending that data in the body of an AJAX request.  However, it would be nice to be able to send the data with the page request.  Is there a way to place localStorage data (or I guess any data) in the HTTP header such that I can read it with Javascript and store it in localstorage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no automatic way to put something in local storage by passing an HTTP header.

Your idea of reading the header with JavaScript won't work either, assuming you're referring to the page that the JavaScript is running on.  The JavaScript has no way to get the response headers directly.

You could always load your data via AJAX or similar.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I am loading via AJAX, but it requires the extra round trip after the page is requested so the page doesn't have the data for a second.

Comment: @JustinCloud Is there a reason you can't include the data in-page?  `<script>var data = /* your JSON data here */;</script>`?  It isn't always ideal (for caching reasons and what not), but is appropriate for some uses.

Comment: I serve the HTML zipped and stored in RAM for speed and simplicity (also the page can then be cached).  Up until now, I only had about 1kB of custom data which I sent in a cookie and then loaded in client side.  It worked well and was very fast.  Now, I have about 10kB of more data so cookies won't work.  I would like to keep the same design and serve the HTML as a static page. So, this is where localStorage comes in.  Right now, I am doing an AJAX request to get that data, so there is an extra step, but I guess I'll have to live with that for now.

Comment: Also, note that while fresh cookies would require a request even if the HTML is cached, that happens because I use Twitter OAuth and the cookies can be set in the redirects.

Answer (score -1):

only with cookie like schoolbus from localstorage to server and back